# Length (count) of sequences with start and end condition Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, conditional-statements

I have some acceleration data for which I am trying to count the length of sequences given a set of conditions. In this case I want to count the length of a sequence when the acceleration `moves > 2.78` and then drops back below `0`.

An example would be

```
[-1.1, -1, 0, 1.2, 1.8, 2, 2.88, 2.86, 2.53, 1.98, 1.21, 0.89, 0.11, -0.21]
```

The return result here would be a count of 7 (2.88, 2.86, 2.53, 1.98, 1.21, 0.89, 0.11)

I have done this previously to identify the length of sequences strictly >2.78 using the following code. I need to build on this to provide lengths using 0 as the endpoint.

```
def get_Accel_lengths( array ) :
    s = ''.join( ['0' if i < 2.78 else '1' for i in resultsQ4['AccelInt']] )
    parts = s.split('0')
    return [len(p) for p in parts if len(p) > 0]
Q4Accel = get_Accel_lengths(resultsQ4['AccelInt'])
Q4Accel = pd.DataFrame(Q4Accel)
Q4Accel
```

Using the above example, the result for this code would be `2` (`2.88`, `2.86`)

Comment: Hi Ann thanks for your input, this only counts the values >2.78, I need to count the subsequent values following a >2.78 occurrence all the way back down to 0.

Comment: I might understand *I need to count the subsequent values following a >2.78*, but i don't understand *all the way back down to 0.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> will this work if there are multiple times this occurs in the dataset?
> I want to identify each one.

Let's switch from `takewhile` and `dropwhile` to `groupby` with a global boolean flag to identify multiple sequences.  I'm simply going to concatenate your data onto itself to simulate two sequences:

```
from itertools import groupby

def keyfunc(datum):
    global in_sequence

    if datum < 0:
        in_sequence = False
    elif datum > 2.78:
        in_sequence = True

    return in_sequence

data = [
    -1.1, -1, 0, 1.2, 1.8, 2, 2.88, 2.86,
    2.53, 1.98, 1.21, 0.89, 0.11, -0.21,
    -1.1, -1, 0, 1.2, 1.8, 2, 2.88, 2.86,
    2.53, 1.98, 1.21, 0.89, 0.11, -0.21,
]

sequences = []
in_sequence = False

for valid, sequence in groupby(data, keyfunc):
    if valid:
        sequences.append(list(sequence))

print(*sequences, sep='\n')
print(*map(len, sequences), sep='\n')
```

**OUTPUT**

```
> python3 test.py
[2.88, 2.86, 2.53, 1.98, 1.21, 0.89, 0.11]
[2.88, 2.86, 2.53, 1.98, 1.21, 0.89, 0.11]
7
7
>
```

> Is it possible to tighten it up though to only provide the len numbers
> as I want to then convert into a df and export to csv?

Perhaps something like this:

```
from itertools import groupby

data = [
    -1.1, -1, 0, 1.2, 1.8, 2, 2.88, 2.86,
    2.53, 1.98, 1.21, 0.89, 0.11, -0.21,
    -1.1, -1, 0, 1.2, 1.8, 2, 2.88, 2.86,
    2.53, 1.98, 1.21, 0.89, 0.11, -0.21,
]

def sequence_lengths(data):
    in_sequence = False

    def keyfunc(datum):
        nonlocal in_sequence

        if datum < 0:
            in_sequence = False
        elif datum > 2.78:
            in_sequence = True

        return in_sequence

    lengths = []

    for valid, sequence in groupby(data, keyfunc):
        if valid:
                lengths.append(len(list(sequence)))

    return lengths

print(sequence_lengths(data))
```

Comment: this looks promising. I will try with my data and let you know!

Comment: Perfect! it works well. Is it possible to tighten it up though to only provide the len numbers as I want to then convert into a df and export to csv?

Comment: @Jake, I took a stab at packaging it up along the lines you suggest.  You may need to tweak it for your needs (e.g. the return value.)   You could also modify it to pass the limits as arguments instead of hardcoding them.

Answer (score 3):

Using `itertools.dropwhile` and `takewhile`:

```
l = [-1.1, -1, 0, 1.2, 1.8, 2, 2.88, 2.86, 2.53, 1.98, 1.21, 0.89, 0.11, -0.21]
list(takewhile(lambda x: x > 0, dropwhile(lambda x: x < 2.78, l)))
```

Output:

```
[2.88, 2.86, 2.53, 1.98, 1.21, 0.89, 0.11]
```

Or just to get `len`:

```
sum(1 for _ in takewhile(lambda x: x > 0, dropwhile(lambda x: x < 2.78,  l)))
# 7
```

Comment: Awesome thanks Chris. So this identifies the numbers but how about just giving a count of how many there are in each sequence e.g. 7 here? Also, will this work if there are multiple times this occurs in the dataset? I want to identify each one. Thanks!

Comment: @Jake I've updated the answer to get `len`. Unfortunately, this will _not_ work if you were to extract multiple times :(

Comment: Ah damn this is exactly what I need just there are multiple occurrences. This only grabs the first. Thanks for getting me this far!